# How to deal with errors coming from ansible roles

Tags: ansible

I have been calling a playbook having multiple roles, each roles signifies a TESTCASE. I need to run the playbook without failing it if one of the role fails during execution. For which I am using `ignore_errors: yes`. However, this truly ignores error, I need to print at the end the name of the ROLES which are failed ?  is it possible ?

```yaml
- hosts: WEB
  gather_facts: no
  vars:
  roles:
    - { role: CHECK_CONNECTION, ignore_errors: yes, tags: always }
    - { role: CHECK_CPU, ignore_errors: yes, tags: always }
    - { role: CHECK_MEM, ignore_errors: yes, tags: always }
```

Question: How to execute whole playbook and at the end print the failed roles ?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Q: ***"Execute the whole playbook and at the end print the failed roles."***

A: Use the [*rescue*](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/playbook_guide/playbooks_blocks.html#handling-errors-with-blocks) section of a [*block*](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/user_guide/playbooks_blocks.html#blocks). Create file *include_role.yml*

```yaml
shell> cat include_role.yml
- block:
    - include_role:
        name: "{{ item_my_role }}"
  rescue:
    - set_fact:
        failed_roles: "{{ failed_roles|combine(failed_role) }}"
      vars:
        failed_role: |
          {% filter from_yaml %}
          {{ item_my_role }}:
            ansible_failed_task: {{ ansible_failed_task.action }}
            ansible_failed_result: {{ ansible_failed_result.msg }}
          {% endfilter %}
```

and loop *include_tasks* in the playbook below

```yaml
shell> cat pb.yml
- hosts: all

  vars:

    my_roles:
      - check_connection
      - check_cpu
      - check_mem
    failed_roles: {}

  tasks:

    - include_tasks: include_role.yml
      loop: "{{ my_roles }}"
      loop_control:
        loop_var: item_my_role

    - debug:
        var: failed_roles
```

Use *loop_control* [*loop_var*](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/user_guide/playbooks_loops.html#defining-inner-and-outer-variable-names-with-loop-var) and create unique variable, e.g. *item_my_role*, avoiding potential conflict inside the included roles.

---

Note: If the variable *item_my_role* is used in the included role, the task *set_fact* in the rescue section, if used, will add a wrong item to the dictionary *failed_roles*.

---

Create simple roles for testing

```bash
shell> tree roles/
roles/
├── check_connection
│   └── tasks
│       └── main.yml
├── check_cpu
│   └── tasks
│       └── main.yml
└── check_mem
    └── tasks
        └── main.yml

6 directories, 3 files
```

```yaml
shell> cat roles/*/tasks/main.yml
- command: "{{ cmd1 }}"
- command: "{{ cmd2 }}"
- command: "{{ cmd3 }}"
```

For testing, let the role *check_cpu* fail by setting *cmd2=false*. The play will display the failed role

```yaml
shell> ansible-playbook -e cmd1=true -e cmd2=false -e cmd3=true -i localhost, pb.yml

  ...
TASK [debug] **********************************************************************************
ok: [localhost] => 
  failed_roles:
    check_cpu:
      ansible_failed_result: non-zero return code
      ansible_failed_task: command

PLAY RECAP ************************************************************************************
localhost: ok=7    changed=2    unreachable=0    failed=0    skipped=0    rescued=1    ignored=0
```

Comment: Sorry, I am confused . I have created include_role.yml now how to pass a role to it like `- { role:  CHECK_CONNECTION, ignore_errors: yes, tags: always }` ??

Comment: I've added an example of *my_roles* to the answer. You might want to fit it to your needs.

Comment: its failing on first role and not letting second role to run , I think ignore error is needed ? can i do it ?

Comment: Block/rescue sections do not need *ignore error* (RTD). Other roles might crash if they depend on the crashed role. In the *rescue* section you have to clean/prepare everything for other roles to pass. Purpose of the *rescue* section is to continue the play. Rescue section  should not crash either. If you have troubles follow [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) and update the question.